# Installing unit into RAD Studio

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

I'm pretty new to programming, and I'm learning how to use RAD Studio. I want to use this unit in my project:
https://github.com/OneChen/FMXNativeDraw
I've downloaded whole folder called "FMXNativeDraw-master". But the only way I know to actually use it in my project is to extract it in the same folder as project files. I'd like to install it permanently into my RAD Studio so I can include it in new projects without copying the files every single time. How do I do that?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If it's a component, you install it in a package, which you install into the IDE. If it's just a unit, you add it to your Search Path (Project->Options->Delphi Compiler->Search Path) or add it to your project (Project->Add to Project).

Comment: If this is a set of units you need more often, in several projects, then, instead of adding the directory with the unit(s) to the search path of the project each time, you can also add it to the Delphi library. But if you want it to be recompiled each time, then add it to the project.

Comment: What does *add it to the Delphi library* mean, @Rudy? Do you mean *library path*? Or is there some new magic in Rio that allows you to add your own units to the Delphi RTL?

Comment: Sound like he means, "add the folder containing the unit to the library paths, as configured in Tools -> Options -> Environment options -> Delphi Options -> Library". Units in those paths are accessible to any project you compile.

Comment: In this particular case, you only need the one `pas` source file, and (optionally, it seems) the `inc` file, it seems, and you could consider copying them to your project folder, especially if you just want to test this out in a single project. The repository links to a blog post that explains how to use it. It's in Chinese, but Google translate to English works quite well.

Comment: qGolezTrol: indeed. I meant the Library Path (for Delphi). I for instance always add the directory my Velthuis.AutoConsole (which waits for user input when a console program ends, but only if not started from the command line) to that path.

Comment: @Ken: you could have guessed. And what else is a unit but an extension of the runtime? The Library path makes that more or less permanent.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I guess it is enough to add the unit (and the include file) to the project, wherever they are.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Sure, **I** could guess. But  If you read the question asked, the person you addressed with the comment probably could not.